# Pass date in url in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have this Link in my view

```
 <a href="{{route('detail', ['id'=>$row->id, 'date'=>Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y') ])}}">
 Link
 </a>
```

when i click on this link this url is called

> detail?id=2&date=03-22-2022

getting this error :

> Could not parse '03-22-2022': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse
> time string (03-22-2022) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character

but if my url is

> detail?id=1&date=03%2F22%2F2022

then it is working how can i urlencode in laravel

> Controller:

```
public function Detail(Request $request)
    {
         
        $start_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->date));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: @JohnLobo I want to convert this detail?id=2&date=03-22-2022 to detail?id=2&date=03%2F22%2F2022

Comment: no need to url encode .you have error in controller method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller method use `Carbon::createFromFormat` and import carbon like below

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

then in method

```
public function Detail(Request $request)
{
         
       $startDate=Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$request->date);

       dd($startDate->toDateTimeString());
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but getting same error, Could not parse `'03-22-2022': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (03-22-2022) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character` but if i convert it to `date=03%2F22%2F2022` this format then it is working

Comment: @i have tried with /detail?id=2&date=03-22-2022 and got exact value "2022-03-22 06:47:26 so not sure what exactly causing here for you

Comment: @user3653474 are you using date or carbon create method which i mentioned in answer

Comment: I'm using Carbon create method

Comment: @user3653474 then it should work. make sure url data is exactly /detail?id=2&date=03-22-2022 pattern not url encode, if its url encode then change $startDate=Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$request->date);

Comment: Thanks i will try, if my date in url is in this format `date=03%2F24%2F2022`  will i be able to parse it using the same function  `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$request->date); `

Comment: @user3653474 yes it will be possible to parse.let me know if you still have an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlencode` function.

```
   <a href="{{route('detail', ['id' => $row->id, 'date' => urlencode(Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y')) ])}}">
     Link
   </a>
```

Comment: Thanks Getting same error, i have to convert this `detail?id=2&date=03-22-2022` to `detail?id=2&date=03%2F22%2F2022`

Comment: `urlencode(route('detail', ['id' => $row->id, 'date' =>Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y') ]))` try like this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass timestamp.

```
<a href="{{route('detail', ['id'=>$row->id, 'date'=> \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp ])}}">
    Link
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function Detail(Request $request)
{
    $start_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp);
}
```